# Do-While loop not operating properly in Java

Tags: java, arrays, do-while

So this should continue to loop until user hits "ENTER" or the array is filled.  But after entering the first element in the array it quits the loop.

```
do 
{
    System.out.print("Enter name (or <ENTER> if done): ");
    names[index] = kb.nextLine();
    if(! (names[index].equals(""))) 
    {

        System.out.print("Enter phone number: ");
        phone[index] = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter email address: ");
        email[index] = kb.nextLine();

        index++;
        break;
    }
} while ( ! (names[index - 1].equals("")) && index < SIZE);
```

Corrected

```
do
{
        System.out.print("Enter name (or <ENTER> if done): ");
        names[index] = kb.nextLine();

        if(! (names[index].equals("")))
            {

            System.out.print("Enter phone number: ");
            phone[index] = kb.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter email address: ");
            email[index] = kb.nextLine();

            }   
        index++;

    } while ( ! (names[index - 1].equals("")) && index < SIZE);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is very simple. `break;` exits the loop. Remove it.

**EDIT:** Also, in your condition of the loop you use `[index - 1]`. Now, if your input is empty (user pressed Enter) the index won't be incremented and it will point to the previous item. Change it to just `[index]` and it'll work.

Comment: +1 `break` does not exit from an `if` statement. It will exit from the nearest loop. While you're at it, here is some literature about a `break` bug: http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~jdalbey/SWE/Papers/att_collapse.html

Comment: When I remove the break, now the loop won't exit when I hit enter

Comment: Got it.  Moved the index++ outside the if statement, so that it is now incremented if I hit enter.

Comment: @user2993639 Yes, that is another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the break and if-statement. Working example:

```
do {
    System.out.print("Enter name (or <ENTER> if done): ");
    names[index] = kb.nextLine();

    if (names[index].equals(""))
        break;

    System.out.print("Enter phone number: ");
    phone[index] = kb.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter email address: ");
    email[index] = kb.nextLine();

    index++;

} while (index < SIZE);
```

Comment: Removed the break, but now the loop won't exit when I hit enter